# How can I execute a .sh file after cd command in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm trying to install Libressl in a python base docker image. The Python image has openssl by default.

My `Dockerfile` code:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install git cpp make dh-autoreconf -y
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN git clone https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable.git /portable
RUN cd /portable \
       ./autogen.sh \
       ./configure --prefix=/opt/libressl --enable-nc \
       make check \
       make install

RUN echo "alias openssl='/opt/libressl/bin/openssl'" >> ~/.bashrc

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3", "./debug.py"]
```

But, I found that git clone is done well, but the next command failed.

Even `autogen.sh` doesn't seem to be executed.

And how can I source that `.bashrc` file?

When I use `source ~/.bashrc`, source command cannot be found because the command is run with `/bin/sh`.

What could be a problem in my `Dockerfile`?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can createa a subshell using parenthesis `RUN ( cd /portable && ./autogen.sh && ./configure )`

Comment: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html

Comment: In addition to the answers you've gotten, I'd delete the line that mentions `.bashrc`.  Most paths to running Docker containers won't run it at all, and the Python script can't use shell aliases in any case.  Consider using the default `--prefix=/usr/local` to install the library into a "system" directory; the Docker image is isolated from the host system so this won't have conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine several command calls use operator `&&`. Additionally you can use one make call with two targets

```
cd /portable && \
       ./autogen.sh && \
       ./configure --prefix=/opt/libressl --enable-nc && \
       make check install
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @alexander is great.
Another approach for it is: executing shell script from Dockerfile and have all the shell command in one place. make the Dockerfile more elegant.

for example :

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
RUN ./app/script.sh
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3", "./debug.py"]
```

and the script.sh (you write as simple shell script) (copy\past what you published without testing ) :

```
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install git cpp make dh-autoreconf -y
pip3 install requests
git clone https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable.git /portable
cd /portable \
       ./autogen.sh \
       ./configure --prefix=/opt/libressl --enable-nc \
make check
make install

echo "alias openssl='/opt/libressl/bin/openssl'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your shell script won't work. It needs && operator as long as you combine commands in one line with `\\`